# Why does not Django release fetched db objects?

Tags: python, django, memory-leaks

I have very simple django app:

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="")
        desc = models.TextField(default="")
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from models import Product

def fetch(request):
        for p in Product.objects.all()[:300000]:
                pass
        return HttpResponse("done")
```

I've loaded 300k sample records in MySQL database, turned debug off in `settings.py` and tried executed `fetch` view - after it completes, django still sits on 700Mb of RAM

I understand that it needs memory to fetch all these 300k objects, but **why on earth it keeps them after view functions exits?**

Again, I'm with `DEBUG=False`, tried this with django dev web server and also with `uwsgi` and its the same weird behavior.

P.S. Verified with Django 1.4 and 1.5.4 on both python2.6/2.7 Linux 64-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really anything to do with Django. Generally, Python does not return memory to the operating system until it needs to.

See [the effbot's explanation](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm) for more detail.

Comment: But somehow if I just allocate array of strings instead of Django QuerySet it gets freed after I exit a view function. There must be something different about querysets. Following your thinking, I can suggest that using Django ORM for anything but small data sets is absolutely impractical.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if strings were handled differently then other (non-primitive) objects. But I haven't tested it.

Comment: Well, Exelian, you are right - creating a bunch of dummy class instances instead of model objects produces the same behavior. So its not a django, its a Python's memory management.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the culprit

```
for p in Product.objects.all()[:300000]:
```

The slicing forces the QuerySet to evaluate, ie. hit the database, and it then returns a `list()` containing the slice of objects, which you then can iterate over.
And [Django's QuerySet cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets) keeps it in memory since you might want to iterate over the same "QuerySet" again.

You could optimize this by using an iterator.

It's in the [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: I have no problem with returning 300k objects from DB. But it expect them to be freed when view function finishes - this is what my question is about.