# Django ORM large db fetch gets process killed

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I fetch about 400k records using Django ORM likewise

```
rs_people = Person.objects.all() # about 400k records
```

Problem is that my process gets Killed due to high memory usage, maybe a leak? I found a similar issue posted here - [Why does not Django release fetched db objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540811/why-does-not-django-release-fetched-db-objects) but there was no offered solution.

I must agree with @Zaar Hai's comment "I can suggest that using Django ORM for anything but small data sets is absolutely impractical."

Does someone have experience in fetching over half a million records using Django ORM with success?

Comment: What do you actually want to *do* with 400K records? There's probably a more efficient way than just fetching them: you may want an iterator, for example. But you'll need to give more details.

Comment: You need this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator

Comment: I am using MySQL. I also added:  'DATABASE_OPTIONS': {
            'connect_timeout': 600,
        }, to my settings.py. It didn't help.

Comment: I want to fetch all these records, summarize the information and archive them to another table, then delete the original 400k.

Comment: So it's a one off python script basically. That means you prioritize "anything that works" over being programmatically ideal. If you can, iterate over chunks of records and operate on less data at a time. Say 5k, 50, 100k at a time, whatever fits in your memory. Use things like https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.iterator

Comment: Ok, thanks so much for all your answers. I understand @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita comment, yes, it can be done, I should try it if nothing resolves this. But now I reorganized the code and have it simplified to: `code`  
                CurrencyReadingData.objects.filter(datetime__lt = from_time).exclude(id__in=[o.crd_record_id for o in CurrencyReadingDataMostRecent.objects.all()]).delete()                
                  and it still Kills the process. Maybe my connect_timeout above is wrong?

Comment: CurrencyReadingData has 157k records. CurrencyReadingDataMostRecent has 600k records. Its a simple delete, why would it have the process Killed.

Comment: Whoah, you're passing a list of 600K ids into an exclude statement? And you wonder why it's timing out?

Comment: So, Daniel, do I just need to run a .Raw command? Would excluding using raw SQL likewise _raw = 'delete FROM  ar_currencyreadingdata WHERE  datetime < ADDDATE(  "%s", INTERVAL 1 SECOND_MICROSECOND ) and id not in (select crd_record_id from ar_currencyreadingdatamostrecent)' % (from_time) be better?

Comment: Ok, solved it, thanks guys. I ended up running cursor.execute(sql_command_raw) command. It takes about 2 minutes to execute but frees Django ORM from having to handle that large recordset.